# Index rebuild on sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, sql-server-2008-r2

I am doing the index rebuilding on database.
I need to verify if it is done or not.
Can somebody please guide me.
I am using SQL Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 8):

If you are looking for details on all indexes and tables in your database you can use.

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(object_id),* 
FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(DB_ID(),NULL,NULL,NULL,'SAMPLED')
```

It just occurred to me that you might also be asking how to know the progress of the reindexing. For this you can use

```
SELECT percent_complete 
from sys.dm_exec_requests 
where session_id= <spid of interest>
```

Comment: I had an index rebuild job ran for 12 hours. Running the percent complete query and the result returned was 0. LOL.

Comment: @MaDDoG - Actually looking at the docs it seems this column is only populated for `ALTER INDEX REORGANIZE`. The docs did also use to say that `CREATE INDEX` updated this column but looks as though [that claim has now been removed](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/641790/doc-sys-dm-exec-requests-topic-is-inconsistent-between-versions)

Comment: Realize this is an ancient thread but I'm in same boat @MaDDoG - desperately need to know the rebuild status but no way to find it still (?) in 2023 ... smh.

Comment: @Christopher - If you do `SELECT * FROM sys.dm_exec_query_statistics_xml(session_id)` then this **might** give you the "in flight" actual execution plan and allow you to see progress, I haven't tested that

Answer (score 1):

If you have successfully re-indexed your tables, then the index fragmentation will be zero (or close to if you have hot tables).  You can use this script to check the fragmentation level

```
DECLARE 
@IndexID int,
@TableID int,  
@IndexName varchar(256) 

--Enter index name here
SELECT @IndexName = '<index name>'
--Enter table name here
SET @TableID = OBJECT_ID('<table name>') 

SELECT @IndexID = IndID 
FROM sysindexes 
WHERE 
    id = @TableID 
    AND name = @IndexName 

DBCC SHOWCONTIG (@id, @IndexID)
```

What you are looking for in the output is the property called *Scan Density*.  This should be close to 100%.  If not, then your re-indexing is not complete/successful

---

If you have lots of tables/indices, this can get tedious, so short-circuit it by auto-generating the script like this:

```
SELECT 'DBCC SHOWCONTIG ' +
    '(' 
       + CONVERT(varchar(32), si.id) + ',' 
       + CONVERT(varchar(32), si.indid) + 
    ')--'  + so.name
FROM sysobjects so 
INNER JOIN sysindexes si 
ON (so.id = si.id) 
WHERE (
    so.type = 'U' AND
    si.indid < 2 AND
    si.id = object_id(so.name) 
    )
```

Comment: Thanks Seth.I have 100 of tables in DB and don't know index name for each of the table.So any other way to do this

Comment: I've added an autogen script that should give you the same script as above for each table and index.

Comment: Corrected table alias. And added the `so.name` at the end as a comment, it helped me to quickly localize to wich object it is refering to. You could throw an `ORDER BY so.name` and the list will be ordered by objects name. Useful script indeed.

Comment: @Yaroslav - Thanks for catching that!

Answer (score 1):

A key thing would be to run the "Index Physical Statistics" report and "Disk Usage by Top Tables" reports before and after you rebuild the indexes.

On the "Index Physical Statistics" report, you can see how fragmented each index is.

To see these reports...
* Right Click on database in Sql Server Management Studio
* Mouse over "Reports", then "Standard Reports", then select the report you want.

For a script you can set up to identify fragmented indexes and rebuild them (and for more info), check this out:

http://www.foliotek.com/devblog/sql-server-optimization-with-index-rebuilding/

Answer (score 0):

You can try this procedure. It will rebuild the index of all the tables in the database and print the result as it progresses to the message pane of your Management Studio:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ReIndexDatabase]
AS
DECLARE @MyTable VARCHAR(255)
DECLARE myCursor

CURSOR FOR
SELECT table_name
FROM   information_schema.tables
WHERE  table_type = 'base table'

OPEN myCursor
FETCH NEXT
FROM myCursor INTO @MyTable

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0    BEGIN
  PRINT 'Reindexing Table:  ' + @MyTable
  EXEC('ALTER INDEX ALL ON '+@MyTable+'
  REBUILD WITH (FILLFACTOR = 80, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF,
                STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = ON)');

  FETCH NEXT FROM myCursor INTO @MyTable
END

CLOSE myCursor
DEALLOCATE myCursor
EXEC sp_updatestats
```

You can see this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188388.aspx) for more on re-indexing **or** this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181671.aspx).

*Note* the information at the top of the page.